# What is the suggested way to modify / override / extend built-in Jackson 2 ObjectMapper in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Currently I have a minimalistic *Spring* / *Netty*, *Reactor* / *Web Flux* project with Jackson libraries

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedSpringServer extends DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MyController controller() {
        return new AdminController();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EmbeddedSpringServer.class);
        HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext).build();
        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
        HttpServer.create("0.0.0.0", 8082).newHandler(adapter).subscribe();
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.2.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.0.2.RELEASE'
        compile 'io.projectreactor.ipc:reactor-netty:0.7.2.RELEASE'

        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.3'
```

Controller class works fine (it returns a `Mono<>` with a DTO type).
Because Jackson is present in classpath *Web Flux* automatically creates an Object Mapper instance via `DefaultServerCodecConfigurer` however it's not clear how to override object mapper instance, because most *Web Flux* configuration classes are package private.

What I'd like to achieve is to create my own object mapper to add custom `LocalDateTime` serialization implemented in [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
   .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
   .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
   .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
;
```

The problem is that's it's not clear how to modify `Jackson2JsonEncoder` created in package private `org.springframework.http.codec.support.AbstractCodecConfigurer.AbstractDefaultCodecs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable that Jackson feature right from your `application.properties` file with:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out simpler than I thought initially as `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` already has a `configureHttpMessageCodecs` method overriding which is enough

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedSpringServer extends DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MyController controller() {
        return new MyController();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EmbeddedSpringServer.class);
        HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext).build();
        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
        HttpServer.create("0.0.0.0", 8082).newHandler(adapter).subscribe();
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper()));
        configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper()));
    }
}
```

as for the Spring Boot I think it can be also achieved by returning a webFluxConfigurer bean

```
@Bean
WebFluxConfigurer webFluxConfigurer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new WebFluxConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper());
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper());
            }
        };
    }
```

as they are picked by `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` created by `@EnableWebFlux` automatically.

**N.B. default implementation of `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` already registers these date modules automatically** the problem with dates was not related, I ended with

```
@Override
    protected void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
        .json()
          .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .build()));
    }
```

to achieve simple date serialization.